# Backbone.js best practice for event handlers naming

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, naming-conventions

Let's say I have a function in a view that triggers when some kind of state is changed.
What would be best to name it and why?

- stateChange
- stateChanged
- onStateChange
- onStateChanged

Comment: Is there anything in particular that that stops this question from being titled "_JavaScript_ best practice for event handler naming"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I personally prefer to use **`onEventName`** names keeping the native naming convention for DOM event handlers.

Like  `myElement.onclick = function() { /* ... */ }` for `click` event.

So for **`myEvent`** I'm using a handler named **`onMyEvent`**.

And if I have event **`stateChange`**, then I'll use **`onStateChange`** handler.

But really this question is more specific for each team of developers and **code-style conventions** inside the team/company.

So the main goal in such kinds of questions is to keep the code style the same in all parts to ensure readability.

Therefore if you're working in a team, just keep sticky to the team's code writing conventions and if you're working alone on existing code, try to keep its code style (sure if that style is not obviously ugly).

**UPDATE: Understanding.**

**What is the event?** Roughly it's an action initiated outside or inside the program, in other words, something happens in the system, e.g. some state changes (the state of the keyboard, of the mouse, of I/O devices, etc.) doesn't matter how (the user clicked on mouse or some program sent the mouse click signal to the system).

Say the browser window is subscribed to get notifications about some events and the operating system sends them to it as soon as possible, we'll assume that at the same time when something happens. So if the user clicks his mouse when the browser window is active and the document has a focus, the browser says to the document to fire the `click` event. And here our `onclick` handler starting its invocation. In other words, the system says to us that now happens a **change of some state**. And we're handling this **change** and not handling a fact saying to us that the state has been changed.

**Let's assume that our handler is named `onClicked`.** Since the handler's name saying in past tense we can get a reasonable question: "When clicked, how long ago it happened? How many times it was clicked? Hmm, maybe it's too late to handle this action (or actions?) at all...". So this name tells us that something happened sometime in past.

**In contrast when our handler is named `onClick`** it's obvious that `click` event just fired and fired once and we were notified about it immediately. And we're going to **handle** the **click event** - the information saying to us that the state of the mouse changed right now (**not** mouse **clicked**, but the **event of click**).

So the names in the past tense are more appropriate for the cases when we need to check if some state has been changed or not. E.g. if the variable stores the `state = 1` we can call the function **`isStateChanged();`** which will compare the value in `state` variable with the real value at the current moment. And here the past tense is a good choice for naming.

Answer (score 7):

`onStateChanged` because this function triggers whenever some kind of state is changed.

Comment: This answer is very biased and opinion-based. Which is fine, if you are asking for an opinion. I think the OP wanted to know convention or best practice more so than opinion, however. I recommend the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11990334/545296 by @eugene-naydenov

Answer (score 6):

I Googled a few names and noted the number of results returned. You can get some indication of the relative popularity of the most common forms for event handlers:

```
stateChanged 168k
stateChange 81k [1] 
handleStateChange 61k
onStateChange 59k 
onStateChanged 12k 
beforeStateChange 2k
```

[1] Results show stateChange used mostly as the name of an event, not a handler.

Using different event types gives a much stronger recommendation towards the onStateChange form:

```
change [2]
onChange 2000k
onChanged 85k
handleChange 36k
beforeChange 27k
afterChange 22k

click [2]
onClick 48000k
onClicked 58k
handleClick 50k
beforeClick 8k [3]

onDrag 100k
handleDrag 36k
beforeDrag 32k
afterDrag 4k
onDragged 5k
```

[2] Too many results unrelated to programming.

[3] Apparently certain Microsoft API's can anticipate when the user is going to click.

Comment: Regarding subtext [3], it's not that the click is anticipated, what it is doing instead is passing the event to any handler(s) that might be attached and giving the developer the opportunity to modify the event data in some way (maybe prevent the event from continuing or modifying default behavior). A lot of frameworks do the same thing.

Comment: This isn't really the place for making jokes. Someone will clearly take it at face value. I left the comment to make sure anyone reading your answer wouldn't become confused because of your statement.

Comment: Function names should IMHO always start with a verb as they are designed to "do" stuff.  So `handleStateChange` would definitely be my favourite.

Comment: Was the search results filtered by JavaScript? Because different languages can have different name conventions.

Answer (score 3):

My bet is for `stateChanged` due:

- `stateChange` looks like an order, and looks like it receives a param with the *new state*.
- `onStateChange` and `onStateChanged` are more keys for storing the handlers not the name for the handler itself.

IMHO

Comment: This is the method I've been using too. `something.onStateChange = function stateChanged() { /* handle change in state */ };` for "on-". When passing a callback parameter to `.live(` or `.click(`, I usually prefer `.click(function handleClick(){ /* do stuff */}`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go for a 2 factor event name. As an app grows in size, you may have more than one object who's state changes or perhaps a controller that can broadcast change events for more than one object and would therefore want to be able to differentiate between then both in code and in your head:

```
Object1:event
Object2:event
```

As for which event name, I think it comes down to personal preference and consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I think one should make a difference based on the actual moment when the action is happening. For me onStateChange means that it is currently changing and I can be notified about this technically speaking right before the change. 
OnStateChanged means the action already happened and I am notified at the end of it.

So, in between onStateChange and onStateChanged there is an important intention difference. 
First one says "prepare yourself for this change" while the second one says "it's already happened".

Edit: I got carried away by the intention and didn't realize the naming itself. 
Why the on prefix? This is reserved for handlers. The handlers will do something related to (on) that event. 
So I would go with stateChange and stateChanged.