# Blazor EventCallbacks naming conventions - Two-way binding

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

We're currently in the process of defining some naming conventions for a Blazor application. One interesting point is the naming of EventCallbacks and the handlers.

There isn't too much about this topic on the internet, but commonly found websites (like https://blazor-university.com/components/component-events/), the Microsoft examples, as well as ChatGPT, suggest on prefixing the EventCallbacks with "On", something like:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<CultureInfo> OnCultureChanged { get; set; }
```

This seems nice and also matches other SPAs (like the discussion here [What is the right name of event handler? onClick or handleClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048249/what-is-the-right-name-of-event-handler-onclick-or-handleclick)), but what's strange is now, that we can't use the two-way binding anymore; Blazor has the convention of requiring a EventCallback. Like this:

```cs
<TestComponent @bind-SelectedKartenMode:get="SelectedKartenMode"
                      @bind-SelectedKartenMode:set="SetSelectedKartenModeAsync">
</TestComponent>
```

The convention dictates, that the subcomponent requires exactly the naming like this:

```cs
        [Parameter]
        public KartenMode? SelectedKartenMode { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<KartenMode> SelectedKartenModeChanged { get; set; }
```

Microsoft also dictates explicitly, that it is wrong to use event callbacks for two-way binding, so we either can't use the On-prefix or need some awkward workarounds.

It seems strange to have both sides: Microsoft itself uses the On-prefix, but then not respect it in the convention. Are we doing something wrong here or is there a better workaround than allowing both conventions?